# Default value of enum if it's not present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a enum in a model. I want to get its integer value, or it's not set I want to get an integer value of a value which I choose to be a default one:

```
  enum my_enum: [:val1, :val2, :val3]

  def method1
    int_val = self.read_attribute(:my_enum)

    # what if my_enum hasn't been set?
    unless int_val
      int_val = ??? # how to get integer of :val2 ???
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Default value for an enum is the value you set at the 0th index.
For ex. enum Animals{ Cat, Dog, Lion, Tiger}  will have its default as 'Cat' which is Animals(0).

However if you define the enum to be enum Animals{ Cat=1, Dog=2, Lion=3, Tiger=0} then the default will be 'Tiger'

Considering that you can define your enum to fulfil your requirement

Comment: when "my_enum" in a database is nil, it also returns nil

Answer (score 0):

It's good practive to set the default value of a field in the database. Try using a database migration to change/add the default value to the required field. Example code:

```
class ChangeDefaultValueToModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_default :model_name, :field_name,  default_value
  end
end
```

For more detail check the Ruby on Rails API for [change_column_default](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_default)